# Kafka Log Retention does not work for topic

Tags: apache-kafka

For a Kafka topic I set `segment.ms` and `retention.ms` to `86400000ms` (1 day).

With this topics config my assumption is that Kafka will roll a log segment after 1 day and also delete it, because retention.ms is also set to one day.

However, nothing happened. The segments are not rolled and therefore not deleted. At least I see nothing in the server logs and the free space is shrinking continuously.

Mysteriously, if I set `segment.ms` and `retention.ms` to a smaller value, for example `1800000ms` (30 minutes), everything is working perfectly.

Comment: How long did you wait after setting that property? Kafka deletes log segments on a periodic task, not drop data immediately. For example, did you monitor the topic longer than 24hrs?

Comment: Yes we did, but it should be possible to set this periodic delay of the log cleaner, right?

Comment: You mean the default `log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000`?